# javascript/jquery override preventdefault?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a site which has an installed plugin which adds a click event to a button and calls preventDefault in the event handler.

I need to respond to the click event on the same button, but my code is never called when the plugin is enabled, which I assume is because the plugin has called preventDefault for the event.

Is there a way round this?

**Edit**

```
alert('pageload');
document.getElementById('add-to-cart-button-45890').addEventListener('click', function(){
alert('addtocart');
fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
content_ids: ['145890'],
content_type: 'product',
value: 45.00,
currency: 'GBP'
});});
$('#add-to-wishlist-button-145890').on('click',function() {
fbq('track', 'AddToWishlist', {
content_ids: ['145890'],
content_type: 'product',
value: 45.00,
currency: 'GBP'
});});
```

This is what I've tried so far. The alert('pageLoad') is hit. I've tried both javascript and jquery to add my click event handler.

And to reiterate, if I disable the plugin, my code works just fine.

Comment: Can you provide the code you've tried, this will be most helpful! :-)

Comment: `preventDefault()` wouldn't stop any additional event handlers you assign from working. We need to see your code to help you

Comment: You should check if when you click the button it actually enters the code you've supplied for the event. As @RoryMcCrossan said, `preventDefault()` only prevents the default effect of the button click, it does not prevent any other actions assigned to the button.

Comment: good to know it's not preventDefault - thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your comments. @Mihail - if you note in my code, I have an alert in the click handler to tell me whether or not the code is being hit.

I have actually now solved it - it seems to have been a timing issue in that the plugin was manipulating the element on page load and I think that was somehow preventing my event handlers from working. I've wrapped my code in window.onload and it works just fine now